# Flask Email Conformation For Password Reset

Tags: python, email, flask, jinja2, confirm

I have a username and password I built from scratch, this works fine until I thought, people forgetting their password.

I would like to find a way to check when a url has been visited to then change the password for urls like "example.com/fp?id=" that has been sent by email.

I cannot use the flask-security module at this point due to the way I have created the databases and how its integrated into my website.

Yes I have looked, and it seems most ways require using flask-login and flask-security, thanks for any answers in advance :)

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation why your database doesn't allow to identify the user by their email address and to email a URL with a JWT token as a parameter containing a unique ID of the user?

Comment: [This article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support) uses Flask-Login though. However, using the extension is not necessary to implement the password reset procedure. It may lead you to a solution that works with your database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed! I just sent an email using smptlib and determining the id using that